# Login_check route in api platform doesn't work

Tags: authentication, symfony, jwt, yaml, api-platform.com

hello i generate a route to login with api platform and jwt but it doesn't work, i got this error "Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured."

security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider

    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:


        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true

            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:

        #- { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/server, roles: ROLE_SERVER }
        # - { path: ^/kithen, roles: ROLE_KITCHEN }


when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

routes.yaml :

```
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

i tried a lot of things nothing works, please someone help me, if you need more informations just tell me
thnx

Comment: What's your api platform version ? Also, have you check [the api platform documentation for jwt](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#configuring-the-symfony-securitybundle) ? You can see that there are some things that differs between your code and the example in doc

Answer (score -1):

try to put your api configuration in security.yaml before the main firewall

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider

providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:


    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true

        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~

    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:

    #- { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/server, roles: ROLE_SERVER }
    # - { path: ^/kithen, roles: ROLE_KITCHEN }
```